# Arduino & PHP query

Tags: php, arduino

I am new to arduino and PHP, I am trying to send temperature and humidity readings from the arduino uno with the ethernet shield to a PHP webpage and then control a fan, some valves and so on from the PHP webpage.  My first problem is I can't get the temperature reading to actually display on the PHP webpage. Please see the attached arduino code and PHP code. I would really apprecaite any help or suggestions on this.

Thanks

Arduino Code:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>           //library for ethernet functions
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Client.h>             //library for client functions


// Ethernet settings
byte mac[] = {0x90,0xA2,0xDA,0x0D,0x8B,0xB3};  //Replace with your Ethernet shield MAC
byte ip[] = { 192,168,1,105};  //The Arduino device IP address
byte subnet[] = { 255,255,255,0};
byte gateway[] = { 192,168,0,1};
IPAddress server(192,168,1,110);        // IP-adress of server arduino sends data to

EthernetClient client;

bool connected = false;

int sensorInPin = 0;
float temperature = 0;

void setup(void)
{

Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Initializing Ethernet.");
delay(1000);
Ethernet.begin(mac);

Serial.println("LM35 Sensor ");
analogReference(INTERNAL);


}
void printTenths(int value)
{
// prints a value of 123 as 12.3
Serial.print(value / 100);
Serial.print(".");
Serial.println(value % 10);
}

void loop(void)
{


int span = 20;
int aRead = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < span; i++)
{
    aRead = aRead+analogRead(sensorInPin);
}
aRead = aRead / 20;
temperature =((100*1.1*aRead)/99)*10;

if(!connected)
{
    Serial.println("Not connected");
    if (client.connect(server,80))
    {
        connected = true;
        //int temp = analogRead(A1);
        Serial.print("Temp is ");
        Serial.println(temperature);
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println("Sending to Server: ");

        client.print("GET /index.php?t0=");
        Serial.print("GET /index.php?t0=");
        client.print(temperature);
        Serial.print(temperature);

        Serial.println();
        client.println();
        client.println("HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println("HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        client.println("Host: localhost\r\n");
        Serial.println("Host: localhost\r\n");
        client.println();
        client.println("User-Agent: Arduino\r\n");
        Serial.println("User-Agent: Arduino\r\n");
        client.println("Accept: text/html\r\n");
        Serial.println("Accept: text/html\r\n"); 
        client.println();
        Serial.println();
        delay(1000);
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Cannot connect to Server");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    delay(1000);
    while (client.connected() && client.available())
    {
        char c = client.read();
        Serial.print(c);


    }
    Serial.println();
    client.stop();
    connected = false;
    }
 }
```

PHP Code

```
  <?php
  echo date("d.m.Y-H:i:s") . " Temperature= " . $_GET['t0']; 
  ?>
```

Comment: What's the current behavior? Does it print what you expect to serial?

Comment: Yes it print perfect to the serial monitor. It prints the date and time and "Temperature" on the PHP page but it is not printing the variable. However when I read back through the 'char c = client.read(), function it actualy reads back the 1-4-13.... Temperature and the actual variable value, I don't understand this ?

Comment: Sorry, I am confused.. your Arduino connects as a client to some PHP script (the one you show below), and that PHP script just echos the temperature value to your Arduino.  I think everything is working properly, it just isn't a design you want.  You want your PHP script to **STORE** this value, and display it on a different page, when someone else (i.e. **not the Arduino**) connects to the same server, right?

Comment: It does exactly what you asks it to do. The arduino is the client - i.e. webbrowser - which is where the output ends up. if you want to use the information somewhere else, you either have to do as angelatlarge proposed, or run the arduino as a server, having a php-script that - when invoked from a browser - calls the arduino and fetches the information it needs - e.g. something like I have done in the phpscript at http://sickel.net/blogg/?p=1492 (from $fp= ... until $data=split ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments (see [MortenSickel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1396864/mortensickel)'s comment above and others), everything is working correctly it is just a design issue.  What you have:

- Arduino makes a `GET` request to your server to update the server with the current temperature
- The server takes that temperature, and echos it back to the Arduino

From what you've shown, this is all working correctly, however, presumably, this is not the behavior you want.  What you likely would like is the following:

- Arduino makes a `GET` request to your server to update the server with the current temperature
- The server takes that temperature and **stores it somewhere**
- When an internet user (not the Arduino) connects to that server, the temperature is shown to the Internet user.

There are several ways of implementing that.  The easiest might be something like this:

- Rename your `index.php` to `arduino.php`, and have your Arduino connect to that (not `index.php`)
- Add code to your php file now called `arduino.php` to **store the temperature** in a file.  You could do this using the [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) function.
- Create a new `index.php` for your internet user. This one will read the file `arduino.php` creates and tell the internet user the temperature.

There are more complicated issues with how this file could be accessed concurrently, but these are not relevant at this stage.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do, apologies for the poor explanation and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hi,I have created the two PHP files, see code below, but I am getting an error on the page calling the data from the arduino, as fellows: "Undefined Index:t0 in C:\wamp.....\arduino.php on line 6". would my arduino be wrong, I just can't understand why the $GET command can't read the value from the arduino. I would appreciate any help again. Thanks

Comment: Arduino PHP Code
<?php
file_put_contents("C:\Folder......\Hello.txt",$_GET['t0']);
?>
Index.php code
<?php
$string1=file_get_contents("C:\Folder.......\Hello.txt");
echo $string1;
?>

Comment: @user2213717: perhaps you should post it as a new question? It is really hard to see your code this way.  You might also want to take a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79347/reminding-new-users-of-accept-upvote-duty)

Answer (score 0):

You can't send temperature. Temperature isn't a string, it's a float. You should change float to string.